# Connection pool shut down error while doing graceful shutdown in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, event-listener, sigterm

We are using spring boot version "2.3.0.M4" and have set the following parameter "server.shutdown.grace-period=30s". However when we do graceful shutdown(SIGTERM) our endpoint in the end publishes an event and the event listener publishes a message to AWS Message Queue; It successfully serves the HttpRequest however we see the following error on the console while the event listener publishes the message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down
        at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:269)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy155.requestConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:176)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1258)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1074)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701)
```

Is there a way to avoid this issue?